# Python - List Index Out of Range cycling objects to new position

Tags: python, indexing

I've searched this several times, and I can't figure out what's wrong. The relevant lines of code are:

```
WallList=[]
def createWallList():
    i=0
    while i<=numberWalls:
        newWall=box(pos=(0,(arenaSize-(i*2))-1,0), height=.1, width=1, length=(randomValue(0,20)), color=color.green)
        WallList.append(newWall)
        i=i+1

if WallList[i].pos.y>arenaSize:
    WallList[i].pos.y=-arenaSize
```

I'm getting an error in console saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/samwhaverly/Documents/FallDownGameWIP.py", line 76
    if WallList[i].pos.y>arenaSize:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm sorry there's so much here, but I can't figure out what's going wrong. If any of you could provide insight, that would be extremely helpful. I can provide additional details if necessary.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error because your indentation is wrong. Here's what's happening:

```
i = 0
Is i <= numberWalls? Yes.
Make a new wall.
Increment i to 1.
Is i <= numberWalls? Yes.
Make a new wall.
Increment i to 2.
...
Increment i to numberWalls + 1.
Is i <= numberWalls? No.
if WallList[i] <- ERROR: there is no wallList[i]
```